# Cannot find module '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

I am trying to install `fontawesome<0.4.x>` in `Angular8`, but it gives me an error and say :

```
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/0.4.x - Not found

npm ERR! 404 

npm ERR! 404  '0.4.x@latest' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404
```

I followed the process based on [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome)

But after executing the last line (`$ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@<version>`)
it gives me `ERR 404 !!`
I will appreciate your help ... Thanx

Answer (score 2):

When you use @ at the end you need to set the version like the following command.

```
$ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.3.x
```

The official [forawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) npm page has a full description of which version to use for each angular version.

Answer (score 0):

when you use @ at the end you need to specify the version number like

```
    `@3.3` etc
```

If you want the latest version just remove everything starting from `@` and it'll automatically install the latest stable version